# Event topic not delivering data

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I have the following issues:

Created event grid topic Azure
Created custom trigger in adf which created subscription in event topic

I have 2 environments

For the testing environment the trigger is working ok
[image]

For the prod environment the trigger is not starting
[image]

As you see for Delivered items there is 0, but there is an activity in Advanced Filtering why is that?

Thank you

Comment: for event grid filters refer to this [DOC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/event-grid/how-to-filter-events.md) ,                            
 [DOC1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/event-grid/create-view-manage-event-subscriptions.md) and                                         [DOC2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/event-grid/event-filtering.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods to set Advanced Filter event grid from Comments.

- Set the Advanced [Filter](https://i.imgur.com/ZYshSEd.png).

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Make sure the filter selected is within the Event grid.

  ```
                                                     (or)
  ```

```bash
az eventgrid topic show --name <your-resource-name> --resource-group <your-resource-group-name> --query "endpoint"
```

```bash
az eventgrid topic key list --name <your-resource-name> --resource-group <your-resource-group-name> --query "key1"
```

- With CLI or Bash [azure doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/event-grid/how-to-filter-events.md).

```bash
$topicName = <your-topic-name>
$endpointURL = <endpoint-URL>

New-AzResourceGroup -Name gridResourceGroup -Location eastus2
New-AzEventGridTopic -ResourceGroupName gridResourceGroup -Location eastus2 -Name $topicName

$topicid = (Get-AzEventGridTopic -ResourceGroupName gridResourceGroup -Name $topicName).Id

$expDate = '<mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss>' | Get-Date
$AdvFilter1=@{operator="StringIn"; key="Data.color"; Values=@('blue', 'red', 'green')}

New-AzEventGridSubscription `
  -ResourceId $topicid `
  -EventSubscriptionName <event_subscription_name> `
  -Endpoint $endpointURL `
  -ExpirationDate $expDate `
  -AdvancedFilter @($AdvFilter1)
```

```bash
$htbody = @{
    id= $eventID
    eventType="recordInserted"
    subject="myapp/vehicles/cars"
    eventTime= $eventDate
    data= @{
        model="SUV"
        color="green"
    }
    dataVersion="1.0"
}
```